# Как сделать GET запрос?

Tags: python, парсер, requests

Мне дан пример запроса и пример ответа, но у меня не получается встроить его в код

Пример:

```
GET
https://kaspi.kz/shop/api/v2/orders?filter[orders][code]=20013004
ContentType: application/vnd.api+json
X-Auth-Token:token
```

Ответ:

```
{
"data": {
"type": "masterproducts",
"id": "MTAwMDEwMA==",
"attributes": {
"code": "1000100",
"name": "LG Optimus L5 II Dual E455 White",
"manufacturer": "LG"
},
"relationships": {
"merchantProduct": {
"links": {
"self": "/v2/masterproducts/MTAwMDEwMA==/relationships/merchantProduct",
"related": "/v2/masterproducts/MTAwMDEwMA==/merchantProduct"
},
"data": {
"type": "merchantproducts",
"id": "THVjaGVudGUjIzI1MDQ3NDMt0JA1MC0wMQ=="
}
}
},
"links": {
"self": "/v2/masterproducts/MTAwMDEwMA=="
}
},
 "included": []
}
```

Мой код:

```
import requests

url = '''https://kaspi.kz/shop/api/v2/orderentries/MjAwMTMwMDMjIzA=/product'''

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/vnd.api+json",
    "X-Auth-Token": "1TR1gaVnZbOXBzB4mK7y1ODz3Ng/Hs4A9qBgQY8lVtM="
}

response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
print(response.status_code)
```

Comment: ужас...хидеры так вставлять в строку запроса

Comment: А можете подсказать как правильно сделать?

Comment: В документации к API есть только это

Comment: Поправил код в вопросе, но даже так не работает, хотя по документации все правильно

Comment: но токен в открытом виде это сильно. запрос так-то отрабатывает с любым кодом ниже в ответе. но отдает пустой json .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import requests
url = 'https://kaspi.kz/shop/api/v2/orders?filter[orders][code]=20013004'
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.api+json',
    'X-Auth-Token': token
}
response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers )
print(response.json)
```

как-то так. Но параметры запроса лучше отдельно передавать.

```
params = {
    'filter[orders][code]':20013004,
}

response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers,params=params )
```

я вижу что в постмане запрос работает. Но т.к. данные не настоящие ответ пустой
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скопировал ваш код и попробовал с реальным токеном, но все так же ничего не выдает, даже ошибки никакой нет

Comment: @auem а print тоже ничего не выводит?

Comment: Нет, просто ничего не происходит, как будто зависает

Comment: @auem добавьте   `'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0'` в headers

Comment: @auem или люблй другой User-Agent

Comment: Все заработало, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Зачем же вы приклеили к URL заголовки? Мухи отдельно, котлеты отдельно.

```
import requests

url = 'https://kaspi.kz/shop/api/v2/orders?filter[orders][code]=20013004'
headers = {'ContentType': 'application/vnd.api+json', 'X-Auth-Token': token }
response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
print(response.json())
```

Обратите внимание, что переменной token надо присвоить какой-то реальный токен.

---

Более подробно почитать как работать с requests [можно в документации](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/).

Comment: Скопировал ваш код и попробовал с реальным токеном, но все так же ничего не выдает, даже ошибки никакой нет